# Why does upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 using a CD/DVD still require download?

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, dvd

When I attempted to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, there was no autorun feature for the upgrade.  So I went into Update Manager, Settings, and clicked "Add Volume" and it added the DVD I had downloaded and burned.

However, during the upgrade it says "1,164M to download".   How can this be true?  I have almost all the packages on the DVD.

Is there something additionally I should do to avoid downloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad news, I'm afraid.  Canonical removed the ability to upgrade using CD/DVD images from the 12.10 release.

All of the instructions I have seen for upgrading to 12.10 only talk about a network installation, usually using the Update Manager.  See the 12.10 [**release notes**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop). It is also mentioned in the 12.10 Beta2 [**Technical Overview**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/TechnicalOverview/Beta2), and there are lots of comments and complaints out there on the net.

Comment: If that's true, that's a real pain.  As well as two machines, I have many VMs that used this method in the past.  I suppose it's possible to set up a private network repository but that seems like alot of work for a small problem that's already been solved in previous versions. :-(

Comment: I'd also like to reference an extremely similar question from the same day.  It says this can be done form the graphical installer. However there's no information about how to do it from the command line.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/202945/how-to-upgrade-from-12-04-to-12-10-using-cd

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround to this: Boot into the Live media and choose "Test Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu". Now, open "Install Ubuntu 12.10". The upgrade option will now work. :-)

However, an online upgrade is still better as your environment (i.e the software installed & its config is unique to your system. In a DVD upgrade, some stuff may be reset or an interfering application might be installed), however there are bleak chances of this happening.

If the upgrade dialog is not displayed for any reason, you may also run the following command using Alt+F2:

```
$gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Good luck.

Comment: I was trying to avoid an online upgrade because I have multiple machines doing the upgrade.  Plus, 800MB is less than 1.1GB, so I save 300MB already on the first machine.  Additionally, the cdromupgrade script is missing from 12.10.  This was how I used to do it, but now it's not there.

Comment: @tudor Okay. Please try the 'network instllation' option. Check http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download This way you'd save a LOT of bandwidth.

Comment: Isn't the network installer the other way around?  It's a small ISO that downloads everything from a network.  I want to upgrade from ISO or CD with little to no network usage.