# How to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 using CD?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

can anyone tell me how to upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 from a Cd

Comment: Do note that [Ubuntu 12.10 is End Of Life in April of 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to Ubuntu 12.10 you can able to upgrade your Ubuntu OS with the help of Ubuntu Alternate CD. But with the release of Ubuntu 12.10 Steve Langasek from Canonical announced on August 27th, a proposal to drop the Alternate CD ISO images starting with the upcoming Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) operating system. On August 30th, the Alternate CDs were gone from the daily builds and will not be available at the launch of Ubuntu 12.10 Beta 1. For more information your can go through following link

[Proposal to drop Ubuntu alternate CDs for 12.10](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/035675.html)

In case you want to upgrade from the disk which you have downloaded from the internet then follow below steps

**Step 1.** Boot with Ubuntu 12.10 Disk

**Step 2.** Select **Install Ubuntu** Option

**Step 3.** On the **installation type** screen choose **Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu 12.10**

In this option "Document, music and other personal files will be kept. Installed softwares will be kept where possible. System-wide settings will be cleared."
[image]
**Kindly Note that as a safer side kindly take the backup of your data.**

In case you want to update your Ubuntu OS using update manager then follow below post

[How to Upgrade / Update Ubuntu OS to Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) from 12.04, 11.04, 11.10](http://www.techienote.com/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-update-ubuntu-os-to-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-from-12-04-11-04-11-10.html)

Comment: Is there a way to do this on servers via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no CD anymore, but here's a DVD image:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

After that you can burn it to a DVD, then put the disk in.
Then look in the box at the bottom of "software sources" under "installable CD/DVD".