# How to upgrade to a newer release of Ubuntu using the Live CD?

Tags: installation, upgrade, live-cd

I've downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 daily CD and I want to upgrade all my computers using this Live CD (they all run Ubuntu 13.04 presently).

How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 exploiting the packages in the CD? Is there any standard procedure for this?

I tried this:

- I rebooted into Live CD, searching for an option like "Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10" (I think it used to appear in the alternate CD) but found nothing like that. **-EDIT-** Even if the option is not present it is possible to "mimic it" by entering manual partitioning and tell Ubuntu to reuse the existing partitions without formatting them. Ubuntu will keep user's data and install the updated software. Nevertheless this is not a viable solution because after the upgrade one has to reinstall all the programs he needs, since it is like having a vanilla Ubuntu.
- I booted into Ubuntu 13.04 and added the CD to my software sources. I then proceeded with the upgrade however the CD was never accessed and everything was downloaded from the web.

I know, I know... I have other options rather than using the Live CD, namely:

- Forget the CD and setup `apt-cacher` in the LAN
- Copy the deb files from the CD into `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

But this looks unreasonable to me... Why can't I insert the CD and exploit its contents? I would like to avoid `apt-cacher` and if possible avoid also manually copying the packages.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Wait until its released on the 25th then just use Update manger to update. 13.10 is still in beta so not released yet.  But according to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseSchedule) only 9 days to go.

Comment: thanks for the reply but perhaps you didn't read my question thoroughly...
How can I exploit the live CD to upgrade? I know 13.10 is not stable (it will become stable tomorrow) but this is not the point.

Comment: @WarrenHill: 13.10 is scheduled for release on 17th (ie; tomorrow)... The `25` that you see over there is the Week Number while in development... :-)

Comment: Sorry I thought it was the 17th (tomorrow) but when I went to check I must have miss-read the page I linked to. Giordano: Alpha and beta releases are [off topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) on this site you may want to ask on the [Ubuntu forums: Ubuntu+1](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427)

Comment: @WarrenHill I think this is not about the fact that Ubuntu 13.10 is still beta (actually it is RC). This is about how to upgrade using the CD. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this still applies with 13.10 but the answer for 12.10 is here: [How to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 using CD?](http://askubuntu.com/q/202945/107450).  If it still works I suggest you update the question and answer to reflect it.

Comment: That solution will install Ubuntu 13.10 "from scratch" while keeping your home intact. Basically, it is a partial solution.
The problem with this solution is that afterwards you will have to reinstall all the programs you had installed before the upgrade, for example texmaker, hedgewars, postgresql, pgadmin3, git and so on...
Still not equivalent to an upgrade performed through update manager.

Answer (score 2):

You need the **Alternate CD/DVD**, which has all the packages required to perform upgrade. In other words, it is a replacement for the on-line access to Ubuntu repositories.

The Live CD contains only the current version of Ubuntu and its packages and just copies that over to your drive after dealing with partitioning.